# Mosek behavior: What is infeasibility certificate formulae of Mosek?

Tags: cvxpy, mosek

In Mosek's [infeasibility white paper](https://docs.mosek.com/whitepapers/infeas.pdf) it mentions two formulae for infeasibility extraction, i.e.

1. **Without tolerance**:

[image]

2. **With tolerance**:

[image]

Among these, which formulae is used by Mosek?

If its the 2nd choice, how do we set the value of the Є tolerance?

Comment: If you mean the infeasibility report printed in the log then it uses something in between, namely |y|>epsilon for some fixed epsilon that  is not configurable. The infeasibility report is a simple helper tool for human debugging and is not intended to be sophisticated. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks you Michal! this answers the question. 
Yes, we indeed were referring to [infeasibility report printed in the log](http://docs.mosek.com/9.2/toolbox/debugging-infeas.html#:~:text=MOSEK%20PRIMAL%20INFEASIBILITY%20REPORT)